# Measurability of a particular map

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard Borel spaces and let $\mathcal P(X)$ denote the space of probability measures over $X$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence. Consider a map $f:X\times \mathcal P(Y)\to \mathcal P(X\times Y)$ given by
$$
  f(x,p)(A):=(\delta_x\otimes p)(A) = p(A_x)
$$
where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure concentrated at $x\in X$ and $A_x = \{y:(x,y)\in A\}$ is the $x$-section of the set $A$. I wonder whether $f$ is Borel-measurable.

My attempt to the proof is as follows: I need to show that $f_A:X\times \mathcal P(Y) \to\Bbb R$ is Borel-measurable for any measurable rectangle $A = B\times C$, where $f_A(x,p):= f(x,p)(A)$. I have
$$
  f_A(x,p) = 1_B(x)p(C)
$$
which is a Borel map of $(x,p)$. Hence, so is $f$. Please tell me, whether the proof is correct, and whether there is a simpler proof of this argument.

Comment: I think you need to use a monotone class argument to show it is enough to prove this for rectangles. This is mostly a special case of the general result that [products of kernels are kernels](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84078/product-of-two-probability-kernel-is-a-probability-kernel/94692#94692).

Comment: @Michael: how would you suggest reducing my problems to the product of kernels - that's what I thought of, but didn't manage to do. Do you mean that the first kernel is $x\mapsto \delta x$ and the second one is $p \mapsto p$?

Comment: Exactly. And there is of course a natural correspondence between kernels and measure valued maps.