# Uniform probability measure on $\{0,1\}^\omega$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I want to formally define a uniform probability measure on $\{0,1\}^\omega$ (infinite binary sequences). Is it possible? What is the exact definition? I see it should have the property "the set of sequences with exactly $k$ fixed values has probability $\frac{1}{2^k}$", but it's not a definition...

Comment: See http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/InfiniteProductMeasure.html and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/21945

Comment: Kolmogorov's theorems provide a formal construction. But by identifying $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ with $[0, 1]$ using binary representation as usual, we immediately obtain a uniform measure inheritted from the Lebesgue measure.