# Is there a natural way to construct a probability measure on $\prod_{ \lambda \in \Lambda} X_ \lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{(X_ \lambda, \mathcal{A} _\lambda, \mu _\lambda)\} _ {\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be an arbitrary collection of probability measure spaces. (Meaning each $\mu_ \lambda(A)=1$.)

Is there a natural way to construct a probability measure from these on $X=\prod_{ \lambda \in \Lambda} X_ \lambda$?

Of course, one could define something really trivial and stupid like $(X,\{ \emptyset,X\}, \mu)$ where $\mu( \emptyset)=0$ and $\mu(X)=1$. But I want to know if we can do better.

I was thinking of trying to define a measure on $\mathcal{A}= \{ \prod_{ \lambda \in \Lambda} A_ \lambda: A_\lambda \in \mathcal{A}_ \lambda\}$, but I'm not even sure this is a $\sigma$-algebra anyways.

Comment: Have you checked Halmos' *Measure Theory*? I'm fairly sure there is something on arbitrary products there.

Comment: @Reveillark Unfortunately, I don't have access to that book

Comment: It's available on Google.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21945/infinite-product-of-measurable-spaces

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to define the $\sigma$-algebra on product space have a very similar objective like the construction of the topology on cartesian product of topologic spaces. The idea is construct the coarset $\sigma$-algebra that’s make every projection measurable functions, you $\textbf{collect}$ the inverse image of measurable sets by all single projections 
$$\pi_\beta : \prod_\lambda X_\lambda\to  X_\beta,\,\,\,\,\beta\in\Lambda$$
and consider the coarset $\sigma$-algebra that contais the above $\textbf{collection}$. In the link given by @saulspatz good details are explained about the above $\sigma$-algebra.

There is many ways to construct the required probability measure on the product space with the previous $\sigma$-algebra. In pratice the most important result is named [Kolmogorov Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) and have many aplications on Stochastic theory, the result requires some compatibility condition to works.