# Characterizing abstract Hilbert spaces

Tags: set-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let me start with a theorem that we can prove :

If $H$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $E$ is any set such that $|E|= dim(H)$, the dimension of $H$ being the cardinality of an orthonormal basis of $H$. Then $H$ is isomorphic to the Hilbert space
$$\ell_2(E, \mathbb{C})= \{f: E \to \mathbb{C}|\{\alpha \in E| f(\alpha)\neq 0 \} \text{ is countable and } \sum_{\alpha \in E}|f(\alpha)|^2<\infty \}$$
equipped with the inner product $\langle f, g\rangle= \sum_{\alpha\in E} f(\alpha)\overline{g(\alpha)} $

Can we have a similar fact but for general measure spaces? like $L_2(E, \mathbb{C})$ for example? if we drop the countability requirement?

How big can a Hilbert space be? I am assuming if $H$ is separable then its dimension must not exceed $c=2^{\aleph_o}$ . 
If $H$ is not separable, can it have a dimension bigger than $c$ ? how about arbitrarily bigger ?

This questions is important for some problems in operator theory, we are given an abstract Hilbert space $H$ and we are asked to build operators on $H$, we have some nice results from operators on $L_2$ that we want to translate in $H$, so it would be always nice to write $H\cong L_2(E,\mathbb{C})$ for some $E$ .

Comment: $\mathcal H = L^2(X, \mathcal A, \mu)\cong \mathcal l^2(A)$ where $A$ can be chosen to be orthonormal basis, no countability condition required. $\mathcal l^2$ is certainly easy to understand in many cases, while $L^2$ is also useful in others, such as spectral theorem for normal operators.

Comment: what is $X$ and the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ in $L^2$ ?

Comment: Any measure space.

Comment: I am not sure you got my point, $H$ is given as an arbitrary Hilbert space, how can you determine that it is $L_2$

Comment: I don't know what want. Any $H\simeq l^2$ and Any $l^2$ is automatically a $L^2$ with the measure  that any singleton has measure $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your example, $\ell^2(E)$, produces a Hilbert space with dimension $|E|$, so any cardinal can appear as the dimension of $H$.

$H$ is separable if and only if $\dim H\leq\aleph_0$. This is simple: if you have an uncountable orthonormal basis, this is an uncountable family of elements at fixed distance $\sqrt2$ of each other; so $H$ cannot be separable. And conversely, when $\dim H<\infty$ or $\dim H=\aleph_0$, it is easy to produce a countable dense subset.

Note that $\ell^2(E)=L^2(E)$ with the counting measure, so you can always do what you want. If you want a "meaty" measure space (say, diffuse), you can start with the separable space $L^2[0,1]$ and consider $L^2[0,1]^{|E|}$. I'm not sure how straightforward or not it is to consider the [product measure on an infinite Cartesian product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21945/infinite-product-of-measurable-spaces), though. I would say that for non-separable Hilbert spaces the advantages of looking at $L^2$ would be greatly reduced as you won't have the usual things that make $L^2[0,1]$ nice (polynomials, continuous functions, etc.).

Comment: I am looking for something with Lebesgue measure if I may

Comment: Lebesgue measure is defined for $\mathbb R^n$, for $n\in\mathbb N$. The space $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is separable, and thus as Hilbert spaces $L^2(\mathbb R^n)=L^2[0,1]$ for all $n$.

Comment: here is my main problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389634/is-there-an-injective-self-adjoint-operator-on-ell-2-mathbbz-with-spectr

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be any non-empty set and $H$ be the space of all functions $f: A \to \mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{a \in A} |f(a)|^{2}<\infty$ where $\sum_{a \in A} |f(a)|^{2}$ is defined as the the supremum of all sums of the form $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|f(a_k)|^{2}$ where $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ runs over all finite subsets of $A$. Define $ \langle f, g \rangle =\sum_{a \in A} f(a)g(a)$. This makes $H$  a Hilbert space and the  functions $\{f_a: a \in A\}$ form an orthonormal basis for $H$ where $f_a (b)=1$ if $a=b$ and $0$ otherwise. The Hilbert space dimension of this space is exactly the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: @NotaChoice The Hilbert space $H$ described in this answer is exactly the space $\ell_2(A,\mathbb C)$ from your question. The countability assumption is automatic (in general, a square integrable function is always supported on a $\sigma$-finite set).