# Is there an injective, self-adjoint operator on $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with spectrum $[0,1]$?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Is there an injective, self-adjoint operator on $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with spectrum $[0,1]$ ?

I basically need to find two self adjoint non unitarily equivalent operators on that Hilbert space which have spectrum $[0,1]$ and empty point spectrum.

Comment: I came to remove this fallacy as soon as I remembered the shift operator has the whole unit ball as spectrum

Answer (score 3):

Since $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ is a separable Hilbert space, it is isomorphic to $L^2[0,1]$. On $L^2[0,1]$, consider the multiplication operator $T$ given by
$$
(Tf)(t)=tf(t). 
$$
Then $T$ is injective, $\sigma(t)=[0,1]$ and $\sigma_p(T)=\varnothing$.

The isomorphism $\Gamma:\ell^2(\mathbb Z)\to L^2[0,1]$ can be made explicit, as all we need to do is map one orthonormal basis onto another. So for instance we can take  the canonical basis $\{e_n\}$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ and have
$$
\Gamma(e_n)=g_n,\qquad\text{ where }\quad g_n(t)=e^{2\pi i n t}.
$$
Calculating the Fourier coefficients for $T$, we get that
$$
T_{nm}=\langle Tg_m,g_n\rangle=\int_0^1t\,e^{2\pi i (m-n) t}\,dt=-\frac1{2\pi i (m-n)}
$$
when $n\ne m$, and $T_{nn}=\frac12$ for all $n$.
So the operator $T'\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb Z))$ with entries
$$
T'_{nm}=\langle Te_m,e_n\rangle=\begin{cases}\displaystyle-\frac1{2\pi i (m-n)},&\ n\ne m\\ \ \\ \displaystyle\frac12,&\ n=m\end{cases}
$$
satisfies that it is selfadjoint, injective, $\sigma(T')=[0,1]$, $\sigma_p(T')=\varnothing$.

Comment: Just a quick answer. I'm not entirely sure if one can use this idea to produce a second, non-unitarily equivalent example.

Comment: Why would $f\to tf$ be unitarily equivalent to $f\to t^2 f$ ?

Comment: well if $f\mapsto t^nf$ then we can have an infinite family of such operators not unitarily equivalent, which I need as well

Comment: can we have an example 'less artificial', there is no way to construct such a thing on $\ell_2$ without using the isomorphism with $L_2$  ?

Comment: and for the bonus question: Find uncountably many self-adjoint operators on $\ell_2$ with spectrum $[0, 1]$ and empty point-spectrum that are pairwise unitarily inequivalent

Comment: @reuns: unitary equivalence of normal operators can be characterized in terms of multiplicity (see Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*, section IX. 10). The condition is not easy to parse, though, and I haven't check it in a long time; that's why I'm unsure. A superficial look makes it seem like for monotone bijective $g$, $M_f$ and $M_{gf} $ are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: @NotaChoice: what would "less artificial" mean? I gave you the explicit matrix entries of the operator. And, that said, how do you plan to calculate the spectrum in your "natural" example?

Comment: I just meant not use the fact that $L_2$ is isomorphic to $\ell_2$ and come up with an operator an $\ell_2$ without thinking of Fourier transform.